# Output 0 of DequantizeAndLinearBackward is a view and is being modified inplace. This view was created inside a custom Function and the autogrid

Tags: python, torch, autograd, activation-function, large-language-model

I am trying to fine-tune GPT J, but I have this error. I think it's related to the activation function and it's in-place but I don't know how to code it to fix it.

Is it a parameter inside the activation function that needs to be disabled? If yes, which one?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
 output = DequantizeAndLinear.apply(input, self.weight, self.absmax, self.code, self.bias)
     14         if self.adapter:
---> 15             output += self.adapter(input)
     16         return output
     17 

RuntimeError: Output 0 of DequantizeAndLinearBackward is a view and is being modified in-place. This view was created inside a custom Function (or because an input was returned as-is) and the autograd logic to handle view+inplace would override the custom backward associated with the custom Function, leading to incorrect gradients. This behavior is forbidden. You can fix this by cloning the output of the custom Function.
```

```
   def forward(self, input):
        output = DequantizeAndLinear.apply(input, self.weight, self.absmax, self.code, self.bias)
        if self.adapter:
            output += self.adapter(input)
        return output
 
    @classmethod
    def from_linear(cls, linear: nn.Linear) -> "FrozenBNBLinear":
        weights_int8, state = quantize_blockise_lowmemory(linear.weight)
        return cls(weights_int8, *state, linear.bias)
 
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.in_features}, {self.out_features})"
 
 
class DequantizeAndLinear(torch.autograd.Function): 
    @staticmethod
    @custom_fwd
    def forward(ctx, input: torch.Tensor, weights_quantized: torch.ByteTensor,
                absmax: torch.FloatTensor, code: torch.FloatTensor, bias: torch.FloatTensor):
        weights_deq = dequantize_blockwise(weights_quantized, absmax=absmax, code=code)
        ctx.save_for_backward(input, weights_quantized, absmax, code)
        ctx._has_bias = bias is not None
        return F.linear(input, weights_deq, bias)
 
    @staticmethod
    @custom_bwd
    def backward(ctx, grad_output: torch.Tensor):
        assert not ctx.needs_input_grad[1] and not ctx.needs_input_grad[2] and not ctx.needs_input_grad[3]
        input, weights_quantized, absmax, code = ctx.saved_tensors
        # grad_output: [*batch, out_features]
        weights_deq = dequantize_blockwise(weights_quantized, absmax=absmax, code=code)
        grad_input = grad_output @ weights_deq
        grad_bias = grad_output.flatten(0, -2).sum(dim=0) if ctx._has_bias else None
        return grad_input, None, None, None, grad_bias
```

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add .clone() to your activation function.
Here, it was:

```py
 F.linear(input, weights_deq, bias).clone()
```